# Css Edge Animation Issue

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

Every browser works fine apart from Microsoft edge, the animation will only start working if I view the element in edges development window, untick the style for the animation then reapply it ?

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
from {background-position: 100% 0;}
to {background-position: 0 0;}
}

#animate-area {
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 9;
background-image: url(/images/clouds.png);
background-position: 0px 0px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
animation: animatedBackground 90s linear infinite;
}
```

Its really driving me nuts

Thanks

Comment: Hi Simon please can you create a [MCVE] so we can try it ourselves to see what is wrong, thanks

Comment: Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lcqfjoeu/2/

Comment: sorry https://jsfiddle.net/Lcqfjoeu/4/

Answer (score 3):

Weirdly IE and Edge need you to state the 0 in the same units as the 100% so you need to use 0%:

```css
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 100% 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0% 0px;
  }
}

#animate-area {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/600x150/");
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="animate-area"></div>
```

Comment: You're welcome, please can you accept the answer so people know it is closed (click the tick below the voting buttons on the top left of the answer).  Thanks

Comment: This answer finally brought me the solution I needed.  Worth noting that the issue presents very strangely in the Edge dev tools-- you can see the outline (or some version of it) moving across the screen if you hover the element in the dev tools, but can't see the element itself.  This behavior led me to incorrectly assume I was looking at some sort of z-index issue, and cost me a lot of investigation time.  Glad I found this solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue just now, but for me it did not work when unticking and ticking the box. Basically had to add a property to the css

`background-origin: border-box;`

Hopefully this helps others whom are having a similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
@-o-keyframes animatedBackground {
from {background-position: 100% 0;}
to {background-position: 0 0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
from {background-position: 100% 0;}
to {background-position: 0 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
from {background-position: 100% 0;}
to {background-position: 0 0;}
}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
from {background-position: 100% 0;}
to {background-position: 0 0;}
}

#animate-area {
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 9;
background-image: url(/images/clouds.png);
background-position: 0px 0px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
animation: animatedBackground 90s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: Ok Added ther new keyframes, still the same :(

Comment: can u please give me live url